# Set theory problem book?

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory

Is there any online resource or a book which has good questions and solutions on basic to advanced set theory? Topics such as ordered sets relations cardinality indexes stes etc are of interest

Answer (score 3):

There is Péter Komjáth and Vilmos Totik's [*Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory*](http://books.google.at/books?id=rbCmt-2NxtIC&lpg=PR2&dq=isbn%3A038730293X&pg=PR2#v=onepage&q&f=false).  I'll admit that I've never looked very closely at this book, but it appears to stay within the realm of more basic set theory.

Jech's tome [*Set Theory*](http://books.google.at/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C&lpg=PR3&dq=isbn%3A3540440852&pg=PR3#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a very large (though still finite) number of exercises of almost every conceivable level.  No solutions, however.

As for online sources, you could try [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory). ;-)